# Replacing end tags using Regex

Tags: html, regex, tags

I have some expressions of type `<h2> text </p>`.

How do I search for the `</p>` tags and replace them for `</h2>` using regex?

Comment: You have not provided details regarding what language/platform you are on. Regardless - parsing HTML with regex is not normally recommended. It is usually better to use an HTML parser.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please refrain from parsing HTML with RegEx as it will [drive you į̷̷͚̤̤̖̱̦͍͗̒̈̅̄̎n̨͖͓̹͍͎͔͈̝̲͐ͪ͛̃̄͛ṣ̷̵̞̦ͤ̅̉̋ͪ͑͛ͥ͜a̷̘͖̮͔͎͛̇̏̒͆̆͘n͇͔̤̼͙̩͖̭ͤ͋̉͌͟eͥ͒͆ͧͨ̽͞҉̹͍̳̻͢](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). Use an [HTML parser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/292926/robust-mature-html-parser-for-php) instead.

Comment: @Truth - Malformed markup problems like this are not necessarily resolvable with an HTML parser. The parser will lose too much information about the malformation. For this case, regex is probably the best approach.

Answer (score 4):

Use this regex

```
<([^>]*)>([^<]*)</[^>]*>
```

and replace with

```
<$1>$2</$1>
```

---

so for sample input text

```
<h2> text </p>
<h1> some text </invalidtag>
```

your result is:

```
<h2> text </h2>
<h1> some text </h1>
```

Comment: Please refrain from parsing HTML with RegEx as it will [drive you į̷̷͚̤̤̖̱̦͍͗̒̈̅̄̎n̨͖͓̹͍͎͔͈̝̲͐ͪ͛̃̄͛ṣ̷̵̞̦ͤ̅̉̋ͪ͑͛ͥ͜a̷̘͖̮͔͎͛̇̏̒͆̆͘n͇͔̤̼͙̩͖̭ͤ͋̉͌͟eͥ͒͆ͧͨ̽͞҉̹͍̳̻͢](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). Use an [HTML parser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/292926/robust-mature-html-parser-for-php) instead. Your solution is actually very clever, so I won't downvote, but please, don't.

Comment: @Truth: It seems be question is about 'invalid html'. I,m not sure about work of html-parsers correctly.

Comment: Thank you! Works perfect! I only edited <([^>]*)>([^<]*)</[^>]*> to <([h2]*)>([^<]*)</[^>]*> to look for expressions starting with h2.

Answer (score -1):

You should learn the [regular expressions](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp) usage in the context of javascript or [HTML5](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/att_input_pattern.asp).

Comment: Please refrain from parsing HTML with RegEx as it will [drive you į̷̷͚̤̤̖̱̦͍͗̒̈̅̄̎n̨͖͓̹͍͎͔͈̝̲͐ͪ͛̃̄͛ṣ̷̵̞̦ͤ̅̉̋ͪ͑͛ͥ͜a̷̘͖̮͔͎͛̇̏̒͆̆͘n͇͔̤̼͙̩͖̭ͤ͋̉͌͟eͥ͒͆ͧͨ̽͞҉̹͍̳̻͢](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). Use an [HTML parser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/292926/robust-mature-html-parser-for-php) instead.

Comment: w3schools is a wrong and misleading site. You shouldn't use it as reference for any sort of language. For PHP, there's the [PHP Manual](http://php.net), for JavaScript, there's [Mozilla Developer Network (or MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/). See http://w3fools.com to further understand why you should never use w3schools.